# .NET CF 2.0: Stream implements IDisposable ... kind of?

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework, .net-2.0

I've run into something odd in a .NET CF 2.0 project for Pocket PC 2003 (Visual Studio 2005). I was dealing with a `System.IO.Stream` object and found that the IDE wouldn't auto-complete the `Dispose()` method. I typed it in manually and received:

> 'System.IO.Stream.Dispose(bool)' is inaccessible due to its protection level

The error is referring to the protected `Dispose(bool)` method. `Dispose()` is either private or not present.

**Question 1:** How is this possible? `Stream` implements `IDisposable`:

```
public abstract class Stream : MarshalByRefObject, IDisposable
```

... and `IDisposable` requires a `Dispose()` method:

```
public interface IDisposable
{
    void Dispose();
}
```

I know the compiler won't let me get away with that in my code.

**Question 2:** Will I cause problems by working around and disposing my streams directly?

```
IDisposable idisp = someStream;
idisp.Dispose();
```

The implicit cast is accepted by the compiler.

**Edit:** This was already answered in [question 939124](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939124/how-is-idisposable-implemented-on-filestream-in-net-1-1). The `Stream` class implements `IDisposable` explicitly. That's a language feature I completely forgot about.

Comment: I recommend using the `using` construct, which does a cast to `IDisposable` for you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How is IDisposable implemented on FileStream in .Net 1.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/939124/how-is-idisposable-implemented-on-filestream-in-net-1-1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stream implements the IDisposable interface, but hides the 'official' name Dispose and exposes the method Close that calls it internally. So calling Stream.Close() equals calling IDisposable.Dispose().

And q2:
No that won't cause a problem but it isn't necesary.

Comment: Yeah, I just saw in another question's answers that Stream implements the interface explicitly. That's a language feature I completely forgot about.